# Complex numbers: convert SymPy to numeric (I to 1j)

Tags: python, complex-numbers, sympy

using symbolic calculation in Python I have

```
import sympy
from cmath import *
from mpmath import arg, cplot

z = sympy.symbols('z')

fhandle='z**2'
g = lambda w: sympy.sympify(fhandle).evalf(subs={z: w})
g(1+2j)

# Returns: -3.0 + 4.0*I
# hence the next command fails, because I is expected to be 1j

cplot(g, [-3,3], [-3,3])
```

Crawling the web I only found [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/sympy/IxyOlz-JYrM) which will fix the matter for the `print` command, but will not work with cplot.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You are abusing `sympify`. When you can (which is almost always) write actual code, not strings to be passed to `sympify`.

Comment: @Krastanov This is the minimum working example. `fhandle` will be passed as a string from the web interface. Still abusive?

Comment: Oh, not in this case, sorry. But there is now another bigger issue: `sympify` may parse code through `eval`, which means that you are exposing your app to injections. It is not an issue if you can trust the users, but it is good to know anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option is to wrap the result by calling `complex`:

```
>>> def g(w):
...     return complex(sympy.sympify(fhandle).evalf(subs={z: w}))
... 
>>> g(1+2j)
(-3+4j)
```

After which `mpmath.cplot(g, [-3, 3], [-3, 3])` produces

[image: cplot example]

Note that I've used a named function here.  There's not much point to using a `lambda` if you're going to immediately give it a name anyhow.

Comment: Note: this works because `I` has a method called `__complex__(..)`.