# convert Symengine I to python 1j

Tags: python, symengine

I want to convert `Symengine` complex number `I` to python `1j` so that I can use these numbers in normal python. Currently, I have a code but it runs using `sympy` which makes it slower. Any alternative solution for this or speed up this code?. Here is the code I have:

```
import sympy
from time import time
from symengine import *
def sym2num(x):
    return complex(sympy.sympify(x))
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16716786/complex-numbers-convert-sympy-to-numeric-i-to-1j) is the reference from which I took the code

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built-in way to do this in SymEngine yet (PRs are welcome).

Here's a workaround that is reasonably fast.

```
def sym2num(x):
    return float(x.real_part()) + float(x.imaginary_part())*1j
```